# Why happen here a deadlock

Tags: go

I am trying to understand, how golang channel works. I read a book about the go language and found the following example.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

// Send the sequence 2, 3, 4, ... to returned channel 
func generate() chan int {
    ch := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for i := 2; i <= 100 ; i++ {
            ch <- i
        }
    }()
    return ch
}

// Filter out input values divisible by 'prime', send rest to returned channel
func filter(in chan int, prime int) chan int {
    out := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for {
            if i := <-in; i%prime != 0 {
                out <- i
            }
        }
    }()
    return out
}

func sieve() chan int {
    out := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        ch := generate()
        for {
            prime := <-ch
            ch = filter(ch, prime)
            out <- prime
        }
    }()
    return out
}

func main() {
    primes := sieve()
    for {
        fmt.Println(<-primes)
    }
}
```

When I run this programm, I've got a deadlock, but when I change the generate function to

```
// Send the sequence 2, 3, 4, ... to returned channel 
func generate() chan int {
    ch := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for i := 2; ; i++ {
            ch <- i
        }
    }()
    return ch
}
```

Then the programm will run the infinite loop, but not deadlock. Why do I get deadlock, when I remove the condition in for loop?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What do you mean with blocking principle?

You can see it illustrated in the blog post "[The Nature Of Channels In Go](http://www.goinggo.net/2014/02/the-nature-of-channels-in-go.html) "

for an unbuffered channel:

[image: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-vnJIWvlbP-E/UwDVICJKB9I/AAAAAAAANX0/T04V_58i8Vs/s1600/Screen+Shot+2014-02-16+at+10.10.54+AM.png]

<sup>(Illustration from blog post "[The Nature Of Channels In Go](http://www.goinggo.net/2014/02/the-nature-of-channels-in-go.html) ", written by **[William Kennedy](https://plus.google.com/107537752159279043170)**, Feb. 2014)</sup>

> Unbuffered channels have no capacity and therefore **require both goroutines to be ready to make any exchange**.
>   When a goroutine attempts to write a resource to an unbuffered channel and there is no goroutine waiting to receive the resource, the channel will lock the goroutine and make it wait.
>   **When a goroutine attempts to read from an unbuffered channel, and there is no goroutine waiting to send a resource, the channel will lock the goroutine and make it wait**.

That is what happens in your case with your reader:

```
func main() {
    primes := sieve()
    for {
        fmt.Println(<-primes)
    }
}
```

since `primes` is never closed, `main` remains blocked.
It (`main`) is in step 3:

> in step 3, the goroutine on the right places his hand into the channel or performs a **read**.
>   **That goroutine is also locked in the channel until the exchange is complete**.

The sender never calls `close(primes)`.

Comment: I got deadlock, because goroutine in function generate is the channel is close after 100 loops and primes still wait to receive data right?

Comment: @zero_coding it isn't closed: I don't see `close(primes)` anywhere

Comment: I mean because the receiver does not close, but the sender is close right? No more sender.

Comment: No, the sender never close it

Answer (score 5):

Let's consider a simpler example:

```
func generate() chan int {
    ch := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for i := 2; /*i < 100*/; i++ {
            ch <- i
        }
    }()
    return ch
}

func main() {
    for i := range generate() {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
}
```

With the condition `i < 100` uncommented, the goroutine spawned by `generate` stops after sending 98 numbers. However, it does not close the channel, so `main` has no way of knowing that no more numbers are going to be sent, and it just keeps blocking on the channel. Since `main` is now the only goroutine still in existence (the other one has returned), and it's blocking, you have a deadlock.

Comment: I have read the topic about channel blocking too, but I don't understand, what that mean with blocking channel. A channel consists about sender and receiver. The sender can send something only at once at time, that mean the receiver have to get the package, until it can continues his work. What do you mean with blocking princip?