# How do goroutines work?

Tags: concurrency, go, goroutine

I was following the [Go Tour](http://tour.golang.org/) and I am a bit stuck when it comes to goroutines. I understand that they are very lightweight and that every time a goroutine blocks, another one will start but I can't get my head around how this example actually works:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func say(s string) {
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        time.Sleep(1000 * time.Millisecond)
        fmt.Println(s)
    }
}

func main() {
    go say("world")
    say("hello")
}
```

[<kbd>Playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/VeXrmTa_fB)

I understand that a goroutine is started for the say function with the argument "world", but as far as I understand that should print "world" five times and "hello" once. However I don't understand why the output is as it is:

```
hello
world
hello
world
hello
world
hello
world
hello
```

From my limited understanding of threads from other languages the output should have been something like this:

```
hello
world
world
world
world
world
```

or like this:

```
world 
world
world
hello
world
world
```

Why does the second line execute five times as well? Does anything below a `go` statement classify as part of the go routine?

Also the next slide shows something I can't get my head round again:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func sum(a []int, c chan int) {
    sum := 0
    for _, v := range a {
        sum += v
    }
    c <- sum // send sum to c
}

func main() {
    a := []int{7, 2, 8, -9, 4, 0}

    c := make(chan int)
    go sum(a[:len(a)/2], c)
    go sum(a[len(a)/2:], c)
    x, y := <-c, <-c // receive from c

    fmt.Println(x, y, x+y)
}
```

[<kbd>Playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/SwmbA327Yt)

A goroutine is started for the second half of the slice and then another one for the first part of the slice, however the values `x` and `y` have been assigned two different values. The way I see it the `sum` function will send it's sum to channel `c` and then the next `sum` will send it's sum to the same channel `c` so how can the two variables be assigned two different values? Shouldn't channel `c` have one single `sum` value in there?

I appreciate that this is quite a long question but I wasn't able to find the answer to these questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does the second line execute 5 times as well?

The second line will print `hello` every second 5 times in the `main()` thread.
But *concurrently* the first line `go say("world")` will also print world every seconds five times in a separate goroutine.
The `Sleep` ensure that each routine yields, allowing the other to resume.

Hence the output:

```
hello
world
hello
world
hello
world
hello
world
hello
```

---

> The way I see it the sum function will send it's sum to channel c and then the next sum will send it's sum to the same channel c so how can the two variables be assigned two different values?

Because each send will block on `c` until channel `c` is read.
Since there are two write to `c`, you need to read:

```
 x, y := <-c, <-c // receive from c twice.
```

The [Assignement section of Golang Spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments) allows for a tuple assignment if:

> the number of operands on the left must equal the number of expressions on the right, each of which must be single-valued, and the `nth` expression on the right is assigned to the nth operand on the left.

Comment: Oh. I think I got it. The main is itself a go routine as you said. The hello gets printed because the main gets blocked by the sleep inside the go routine. Because whenever a routine is blocked a new one starts the main repeats 5 times but at the same time the function repeats itself 5 times as well. Hello gets printed first because the code jumps over the routine waiting for it to sleep.

Comment: Also this is another question regarding my second example. Say there are millions of calls to the sum functions with the go prepended to it. If the program doesn't get to the line that blocks the program before the sum finishes computing then that value would be lost right?

Comment: @Bula sorry for the belated answer. Yes, main() is a goroutine in itself, and will yield on the `Sleep()`.

Comment: @Bula no, the value wouldn't be lost: the goroutine which has computed it would be blocked on `c <- sum`, waiting for `main()` to read enough values.

Comment: If I understand right whenever `c <- sum` the program will be blocked for `value <- c` to happen?

Comment: Sends to a buffered channel block only when the buffer is full. Receives block when the buffer is empty. So this only happens because the channel is buffered ?

Comment: @Bula in your example (in your question), the channel is unbuffered (not buffered). So it blocks every time you write until another channel reads. That is what http://stackoverflow.com/a/24908162/6309 illustrates.

Comment: Right. My program gets blocked every time waiting for the channel to receive it. A buffered channel won't block until all of the "slots" are taken. However this buffered channel will serve these pieces of data when `value := <- c` happens in order. Why would you then ever want to use an unbuffered channel? Doesn't it stop you doing a lot of things at once?

Comment: @Bula it doesn't "stop you doing a lot of things at once?" as long as those "lot of things" aren't waiting one for another. But it helps enforcing a strong **synchronization**. An unbuffered channel is an easy way to make one channel wait for another.

Comment: @Bula in this instance (your question), `main()` is waiting for the two goroutines to publish their result in the channel. If `main()` wasn't blocked there, it would exit, finishing the all program(!) including the two goroutines which might have still been in the process of computing said results. That synchronization is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

For the first function you should see values in the style VonC presented. The reason `hello` prints 5 times as well is because the function `say` prints things 5 times. Just imagine the program without the goroutine. I think it doesn't guarantee that you will get `hello` and `world` perfectly interspersed but I may be wrong.

The reason the channel works is:

1. Golang let's you do multiple assignment as VonC mentions
2. Channels `empty out`, i.e. when you assign `c` to `x` it removes the first sum that was passed into the channel and when it assigns `c` to `y` it passes in the second value (again I think the order is not a guarantee as `x` could have the first half and `y` the second half sum or vice-versa.

If you imagine channels as a sort of a queue I think it makes more sense. The summing goroutines push values onto the queue and assignments pop the values sequentially.